# Flutter: How to display all columns in the same table

Tags: mysql, json, flutter, dart

I am working on a test application in Dart. The application is used for displaying and inserting data into a database hosted with 000webhost.com

I am displaying my json data into a table in my app. I would like all the columns to be inside of one table. With my current code it is displaying every column inside of a brand new table
[like shown here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGCdd.png)

Below is the relevant code for my project:

```
class ViewData extends StatelessWidget{
  final String url = 'https://fourieristic-thousa.000webhostapp.com/index.code.php?action=view';

  Future<List<dynamic>> fetchData() async {
    var result = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(url),
    );

    print(json.decode(result.body));
    return json.decode(result.body);
  }

  // First entry of each column.
  String _test(dynamic test, int index){
    return test[index]['testColumn'];
  } 

  // Second entry of each column.
  int _test2(dynamic test, int index){
    return json.decode(test[index]['testColumn2']);
  }

  // Third entry of each column (Will some day be a delete function)
  int _id(dynamic test, int index){
    return json.decode(test[index]['ID']);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test data table'),
      ),
      body: Container(          
        child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
          future: fetchData(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return SingleChildScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    child: DataTable(
                      columns: const <DataColumn>[
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Text(
                            'Test',
                            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Text(
                            'Test2',
                            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Text(
                            'Delete',
                            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                      rows: <DataRow>[
                        DataRow(
                          cells: <DataCell>[
                            DataCell(
                              Text(_test(snapshot.data, index).toString())
                            ),
                            DataCell(
                              Text(_test2(snapshot.data, index).toString())
                            ),
                            DataCell(
                              Text(_id(snapshot.data, index).toString())
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }
              );
            } else {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried looking for an answer online with no result. I have also tried rewriting my code to attempt to find anything wrong with it. I understand why the app is showing the data in individual tables, but I can not find a way to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You claim to know what the problem is so I won't go in depth, but the main issue is your `ListView.builder`; there is no reason to have it there. Instead, you should replace the code between `if(snapshot.hasData){` and `return SingleChildScrollView(` with something like this:

```
List<DataRow> dataRows = [];
for (var index = 0; index < snapshot.data.length; index++) {
  dataRows.add(
    DataRow(
      cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(
          Text(_test(snapshot.data, index).toString())
        ),
        DataCell(
          Text(_test2(snapshot.data, index).toString())
        ),
        DataCell(
          Text(_id(snapshot.data, index).toString())
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

and then put the `dataRows` variable in the `rows:` field of your `DataTable`. Your tree should end up being Scaffold -> Container -> FutureBuilder -> SingleChildScrollView -> DataTable. This way you won't be building a new table for every entry.

Comment: This seems to have fixed the problem. Thank you very much for the helping hand!